# R: substr() results differently in for loop and vector

Tags: r, character, substr

I'm using substr to cut off the last three letters from the string list: postal_code0

```
postal_code0
>[1] "n14BE"   "n14BE"   "n14BE"   "n14BE"   "n14BE"   "N16DD"   "N16DD"   "N16DD"   "N16DD"   "N16DD"  
>[11] "N11TW"   "N11TW"   "N11TW"   "N11TW"   "N11TW"   "n5"      "N160LU"  "N2"      "N200AU"  "N200AU" 
>[21] "london"  "n15"     "N5"      ""    

> outcode <- substr(postal_code0, 1, nchar(postal_code0)-3)
> outcode
[1] "n1"   "n1"   "n1"   "n1"   "n1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"   "N1"  
[16] ""     "N16"  ""     "N20"  "N20"  "lon"  ""     ""     ""
```

It removes some elements completely, which I'd like to keep, but if I use for loop for the same function, it returns the outcome I'd like.

```
> outcode0 <- c()
> for (i in 1: length(postal_code0)){
+ outcode0[i] <- substr(postal_code0[i], 1, nchar(postal_code0)-3)
+ }

> outcode0
[1] "n1" "n1" "n1" "n1" "n1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "N1" "n5" "N1" "N2" "N2" "N2" "lo"
[22] "n1" "N5" ""
```

What's the difference between the two functions? And how to get the

```
outcode0
```

without using for loop?

Comment: What's your desired output? Do you want to keep the first two characters of each string? If so, try `substr(postal_code0,1,2)`.

Comment: (1) I might consider the difference between the vectorized nature of the arguments of `substring` versus those of `substr`, (2) It might be simpler to read the Note section of `?substr` and look into the function `strtrim`.

Comment: well, the thing is: substr(c("n5", "n5"), 1, nchar(postal_code0)-3) also return "n5", "n5". When I substitute with a variable name vector, it just doesn't return the same result

Comment: @nicola I neet to cut off last three letters for the long string, and keep the short ones.

Comment: The loop is using `nchar(postal_code0)-3` as a stop parameter, but that's a vector so only the first element gets used, which is why it returns 2 regardless of the length of `postal_code0[i]`

Comment: You keep using `nchar(postal_code0) - 3`. (You even do that in `substr(c('n5', 'n5'), 1, nchar(postal_code0) - 3)`.  If you evaluated

`s <- c('n5', 'n5)
substr(s, 1, nchar(s) - 3)`

you'd see the expected results: empty strings.

Comment: @alistaire okay, but if you look in the vector, there are still characters with 3 letters.

Answer (score 2):

According to the last comment you left, the following should do:

```
len <- nchar(postal_code0)
substring(postal_code0, 1, ifelse(len <= 3, len, len - 3))
```

Comment: I'm not strictly sure that the question as asked makes sense.  How many characters should the head of a four character string return? 3? or 1?

Comment: Since @Chumoon was interested in removing 3 characters from the end, the way I interpreted it is that if it has less than 3 characters then the entire string is to be returned. I agree that the question could be made a bit more clear.

Comment: @thepule thanks for the answer. Yeh, I was not aware that substr() only take one value in nchar()